# How can I get the day of the year from datetime64 array?

Tags: python, arrays, datetime

I have an array:

```
array(['1980-01-01T00:00:00.000000000', '1980-01-02T00:00:00.000000000',
       '1980-01-03T00:00:00.000000000', ...,
       '1989-12-29T00:00:00.000000000', '1989-12-30T00:00:00.000000000',
       '1989-12-31T00:00:00.000000000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]'
```

And I want to get another array with `day of the year`.

I am not sure how to use `timetuple().tm_yday` with it. Or something else.

Comment: `pd.Series(v).dt.day.values`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Thanks!